# What's your policy on asking the same question twice?

Tags: discussion

I have the exact same problem as this question:

[LaTeX producing black background with transparent png](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79906/13646)

That question was asked in 2012, but I have the same problem today. I could compose my own question, but it will end up being identical to the 2012 question.

My assumption is that my problem will have a different cause and a different answer (I could be wrong).

How would you like me to approach this? Ask a new question anyway and reference the 2012 question, or somehow encourage new answers to the old question?

Comment: Since you're using a newer version of `pdftex` than the one in the other question, I would say your question is different. When posting your question, I would recommend that you link back to the other one and make it clear that your problem is different, to avoid your question getting closed.

Comment: Running the sample document (using the linked `.png`  in that question on using either TL 2014 or TL 2015 doesn't reproduce the problem for me.  It's not clear from your comment on that question whether you see the problem with that `.png` exactly or with another `.png`.

Comment: It turns out my problem is with the `createspace` package and not with pdfTeX, as was the case with the 2012 question. Regardless, it's good to get a sense of how this community works. Sorry for the irrelevant question.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For me the policy is the following:

- Does any answer(s) solve my question or not? If it's the case, no need to ask a new one.
- If no answer(s) satisfy the question (and the OP have the same error as you), you can add a bounty and writing in comment why you add this bounty.
- Otherwise you can ask a new question linking to the previous one saying that no answer(s) staisfy your problem and giving all what should be needed to solve it (MWE, LaTeX code, ...)